# How do I replicate the tinymce link plugin's HTML markup behavior by adding succeeding text outside of the current node instead of inside?

Tags: tinymce

When the user adds a link on selected text, it adds the URL markup only on the selected section and doesn't add the markup to any added text (after the markup is added) if the linked text is at the end of the string. This behavior differs from bold/italics/underline which adds added text to the bold/underline markup if the user adds more text at the end of a string.

I am implementing a custom button that should emulate the behavior of the link plugin. I have gone through the link/plugin.js file to no avail for which code block I need to re-use to get this behavior for my custom button.

How do I implement the link plugin's markup behavior? Are there any tinyMCE commands I should be using (setAttribs, etc)?

[Video example of bold vs link plugin](https://streamable.com/obemki)